# How to compile c++98 code written on RedHat 5 on RedHat 7 Linux

Tags: c++, c++11, std, rhel7, rhel5

I have a c++ application written and compiled on a RedHat5 Linux machine using NetBeans. (`c++ and gcc version 4.1.2`)
I want to compile it on a RedHat7 machine (`c++ and gcc version 4.8.5`).
My problem is that all functions related to the c++ std library are showing an error.

I tried changing the c++ compiler to `c++98` and `c++11` but both didn't work.
All header includes remained the same.

```
// A simple split function that returns vector of double
std::vector<double> ConfigParser::split(std::string combined, char separator) {
    std::vector<double> separated;
    std::replace(combined.begin(), combined.end(), separator, ' ');
    std::stringstream ss(combined);
    std::string temp;
    while (ss >> temp)
    {
        separated.push_back(atof(temp.c_str()));
    }
    return separated;
}
```

```
ConfigParser.cpp:34:5: error: ‘replace’ is not a member of ‘std’

ConfigParser.cpp:39:46: error: ‘atof’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Are you including `algorithm` and `cstdlib` in this file? It might be that some other header did include them in the previous version.

Comment: Yes and it works but some includes will not work on the RHEL 5 version